# Div side by side issue

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my CSS - I am have two divs - "section1" and "section2". I want them to be displayed side by side but they are being displayed as seen in the picture. Does anyone know how to display them side by side?

[image: issue]

```
  <div id="section1">
   <h1><London></h1>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants</p>
  </div>

  <div id="section2">
  <h2><London></h2>
  <p1>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants</p>
 </div>

</div>

#section1
{
float:center;
padding:5px;
background-color:lime; 
margin-left:20px;
width:300px; 
}

#section2
{
float:right;
background-color:lime; 
margin-left:10px;
width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your float property should be **left** not center and right and hopefully that moves them side by side.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add clear:both; or clear:none; to your css. This allows relative objects to park side by side, or be forced below an existing object. This command works best on crowded pages.